# How does acupuncture work?

Tags: human-biology

Can anyone actually tell me how acupuncture works?

There are numerous websites with little actual explanation, but assert that it works. For example the below article:

http://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/acupuncture-is-worth-a-try-for-chronic-pain-201304016042

However I have failed to find any article about how acupuncture works, or the mechanism at play. Can anyone tell me how it works?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Do you have any evidence to support that it actually works? If not, your question is off-topic because "primarily-opinion based". If you are looking for evidence f whether it works or not, then you should go on Skeptics.SE. You will find [here](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acupuncture?sort=votes&pageSize=50) on skeptics a lit of questions tagged `acunpuncture` that will probably already give you some answers.

Comment: @Remi.b https://scholar.google.hu/scholar?as_ylo=2011&q=acupuncture+placebo+controlled&hl=hu&as_sdt=0,5 There are many placebo controlled articles, it is better than placebo. (Btw. it is interesting, how you do placebo acupuncture. :D)

Comment: Dear questioner, let me help: https://scholar.google.hu/scholar?q=acupuncture+mechnism&btnG=&hl=hu&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=2011

Comment: @inf3rno sham needles!

Comment: @TanMath I checked the video, but it wasn't about whether acupuncture works. It was about that doctor - patient relationship has placebo effect which I already knew. http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1moo91_horizon-2013-2014-8-the-power-of-the-placebo_lifestyle

Comment: @inf3rno that wasn't my video.. I was just saying sham needles can be used as control

Comment: @TanMath Ohh okay. :-)

Comment: @TanMath I checked 4-5 article about placebo controlled experiments by different diseases. None of them was better than placebo. It is a bit early to tell, but maybe it is really just placebo. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is acupuncture**

Acupuncture is a form of alternative medicine by which needles are pierced through the skin and helps to treat diseases.

**Science behind acupuncture**

So far, the research on acupuncture has shown that acupuncture can help to suppress pain but probably will not treat diseases.

Really, it all has to do with connective tissue. Connective tissue is tissue that connects, supports, binds, or separates other tissues or organs. In the connective tissue, there are cells known fibroblasts. According to an article in The Scientist (http://www.the-scientist.com/?articles.view/articleNo/35301/title/The-Science-of-Stretch/):

> the cells that are responsible for synthesizing all the proteins that make up the extracellular matrix. These cells reside within the matrix they create, responding to mechanical stimulation by regulating the amount of collagen and other matrix proteins produced, and by secreting matrix-degrading enzymes in response to chronic changes in tissue forces.

Their research also showed that:

> the fibroblasts initiated a specific Rho-dependent cytoskeletal reorganization that was required for the tissue to fully relax. Rho is an intracellular signaling molecule known to play a role in cell motility and the remodeling of cell-surface proteins that connect the fibroblast to its surrounding matrix.

They also mentioned that the fibroblasts secrete ATP, which is converted to adenosine which is an analgesic. This leads me to a second article in in Discover Magazine (http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/notrocketscience/2010/05/30/a-biological-basis-for-acupuncture-or-more-evidence-for-a-placebo-effect/#.VjAmFyPn_qD). In this article, they mention about a paper that described the importance of adenosine.

**Criticism**

The research showed that the A1 receptor for adenosine is important for acupuncture to work. But they mention in the Discover article that there is nothing special about acupuncture. They say:

> o answer that, clinical trials have used sophisticated methods, including “sham needles”, where the needle’s point retracts back into the shaft like the blade of a movie knife. It never breaks the skin, but patients can’t tell the difference from a real, penetrating needle. Last year, one such trial (which was widely misreported) found that acupuncture does help to relieve chronic back pain and outperformed “usual care”. However, it didn’t matter whether the needles actually pierce the skin, because sham needles were just as effective. Nor did it matter where the needles were placed, contrary to what acupuncturists would have us believe.

It is hard to also have a control but it seems the best may be the sham needles. However, much of this research is debatrd.

I hope I have answered your question. Please ask anything more in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

It works via the placebo effect which according to recent research, is [not the sort of trivial effect as it was thought to be](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1moo91_horizon-2013-2014-8-the-power-of-the-placebo_lifestyle).

Comment: What about the research in the articles described in my answer?

Comment: @TanMath What has transpired in recent years is that sham acupuncture and real acupuncture work just as well, the best results are obtained when  patients have long discussions with the doctor about the complaints  before undergoing treatment, whether it is a sham or real treatment.

Comment: but there *is* scientific evidence that it is a physical phenomenon...

Comment: @TanMath The relevance of such induced phenomena must be established. E.g. if I treat patients suffering from vertigo by letting them be subject to a roller coaster treatment, then obviously I'm subjecting them to nontrivial physical effects that influence balance. However, if I'm not doing any better than alternative treatments where they are not subject to such influences, then I can't say that the roller coaster had any effect on the vertigo. My theory may well be very plausible, there may exist experimentally confirmed mechanisms that support my theory. But it's then all irrelevant.

Comment: @inf3rno says that your video wasn't about whether acupuncture works... Maybe another link about placebo and acupuncture is better?

Comment: If you watch the entire video, you'll see sham acupuncture with patients discussing complaints compared to real acupuncture.

Answer (score 1):

Every major, large, blinded, well-controlled study shows that it is no better than placebo.

Here's one article with references:  https://sciencebasedmedicine.org/acupuncture-doesnt-work/